# Where are the nautilus arrows and the status bar?

Tags: nautilus

In older versions of nautilus there were arrows to unfold a folder and see the contents without having to enter the folder (see image).

There was also a status bar, that showed the available free space of the device.

Where have all these things gone and how can I get them back?

[image]